# Carrierwave + Fog Error "Errno::EACCES in ProjectsController#update"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, carrierwave, fog

I am using carrierwave with fog to store images on amazon's s3. I've followed all the guides, but i keep getting the same basic error and it seems incorrectly.

```
Errno::EACCES in ProjectsController#update

Permission denied - C:/rails-projects/myrailsapp/tmp/20111203-2006-7864-6681/jolly-rows.jpg
```

however, the uploaded image is still being placed in the cached dir and it's being uploaded to the amazon s3 server.... so why is it throwing this error?

i have

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
config.root = Rails.root.join('tmp')
config.cache_dir = 'carrierwave'
config.fog_credentials = {
        :provider => 'AWS',
        :aws_access_key_id => 'SECRET',
        :aws_secret_access_key => 'SECRET'
}
config.permissions = 0777
config.fog_directory = 'ia_test_dir'

config.fog_public = true
end
```

in an initializer. please help...thanks!

Update: still haven't been able to get this to work. I've a few other things, like changing the tmp dir, not setting the tmp, etc.. and nothing please help. anyone?

Is there something my question is missing that's keeping people from responding?

Comment: i have same problem, di dyou ever find an answer?

Comment: btw i suspect it is windows related

Comment: found a fix. it's described at the end of this article http://pardner.com/2012/01/rails-3-1-carrierwave-s3-heroku/ basically you need to set config.delete_tmp_file_after_storage = false

Comment: @jpwynn would you post this as an actual answer to the question? I think that would be helpful to other users. I'd do it myself but I don't wanna steal your karma.

Comment: sorry i haven't been back to answer. i've since switched to a macbook so it sorted just worked it self out. @jpwynn if you post this as an actual answer, i'll mark it correct and everyone wins.